# Cake PHP 3 - add bookmark to div id in paginator url

Tags: url, redirect, cakephp, paginator

In Cake PHP 3 how to add bookmark to div id in paginator url?

The div that retains the paginator and its elements is = `<div id=mydivid">`

Paginator url is: `http://myweb.tld/?page=2`

I need to modify it to `http://myweb.tld/?page=2#mydivid`

So that paginator redirects to the same div where it is activated and not to the beginning of the page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**CREATING URL IN A VIEW**

It is in the documentary: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html#generating-urls

```
echo $this->Url->build([
    "controller" => "Posts",
    "action" => "search",
    "?" => ["foo" => "bar"],
    "#" => "first",
]);

// Output
/posts/search?foo=bar#first
```

**CREATING URL IN A CONTROLLER**

Documentary: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#generating-urls

```
Router::url([
    'controller' => 'Articles',
    'action' => 'index',
    '?' => ['page' => 1],
    '#' => 'top'
]);

// Will generate a URL like.
/articles/index?page=1#top
```

Comment: Undefined property: PagesController::$Url

Comment: i'm using it in PagesController inside home function

Comment: Check this link: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#generating-urls

Comment: Using option 2 -> Router::url, the link of the paginator stays like ?page=2, and not like ?page=2#mydiv